# Time Series Analysis - ARIMA

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection

I am trying to make sales prediction from time series data.

[image: Original plot]

After performing a log transformation to the original data and differencing it by 1, I got a stationary dataset. So I plotted ACF and PACF graphs.

ACF graph:
[image: acf]

PACF graph:
[image: pacf]

Does this mean I should use ARIMA(0,1,0) to perform time series analysis?
Also, if I got the value of p,d and q, do I use the original data to perform ARIMA model? For example,

```
ARIMA(original_data, order=(0,1,0))?
```

Comment: taking logs can be useful and can be detrimental .... see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-to-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers

Answer (score 2):

> ARIMA(original_data, order=(0,1,0))?

The `d` term should be chosen after you analyze the autocorrelation in your data and **before** you difference the data. You can also conduct the stationarity test to determine whether you need to take differences. And if you log-transform the raw data in the first place, then after calculating your forecast, you should make a back transform using $e$.

The `p` term reflects autocovariance structure, but I don't see significant values in your plots at lags 1 to 5 (typical range to search in...), so `p = 0` most likely.

If you want to automate this routine, you can check out `auto.arima` function that is available in a library for some software, like R or Python.

Comment: *And if you log-transform the raw data in the first place, then after calculating your forecast, you should make a back transform using $e$.* Right. And since exponentiation is not a linear operation, beware that a point forecast of the mean in logs is not the point forecast of the mean in levels. Also, the shortest possible forecast interval with x% coverage in logs is not the shortest possible forecast interval with x% coverage when transformed back to levels by taking the endpoints and exponentiating them.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thank you. Are you making a reference to forecast interval boundaries? I understand, but is this possible to estimate them correctly in this case?

Comment: The transformed forecast interval still has correct coverage but is no longer the shortest possible. If a particular distribution of errors (innovations, shocks) is assumed, then a shorter interval could be derived, I think. I am not sure a shorter interval could be derived without such an assumption.